# Playing pdf with embedded animations

Tags: video, pdf, animation

I have been trying to find a PDF viewer in Linux with the ability to play embedded animations (with the video data saved into the PDF). I have read tens of forum questions and tried many different viewers (evince, okular, acroread, foxit...) but nothing has worked so far.

However, since all the questions I have seen were from 2015 or older, I figured that by this point (2018!) something might exist that did the trick.

So, is there a way to play embedded animations in PDFs using Linux?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One year ago, Okular added support for embedded animations (animateinline)!

https://invent.kde.org/graphics/okular/-/merge_requests/10

and you can also play videos (media9) without problems (in presentation mode).

Check the 'snap' version instead of the 'apt' version to get the latest features.

EDIT: there are still some bugs being fixed: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=434964